# Git Merge Conflict After Using Visual Studio to Stash the Current Branch Then Switch To Another Branch

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

[All of these actions were performed with Visual Studio 2019, although the question really pertains to Git and Git Stash.]

I have a generic question about Git:

- I had a clean clone of master with no file changes.
- From master, I created then checked out a branch called Temp.
- I changed 5 files in the Temp branch.

I then needed to switch back to master to check something... When I tried to switch to master in Visual Studio, I was offered the opportunity to stash my changes. I stashed then ended up back in the master branch. However, Visual Studio reported that Git detected merge conflicts that would need to be resolved. I do not understand how this could happen!

Furthermore, I tried immediately to switch back to the Temp branch, and Visual Studio reported that I need to resolve merge conflicts before I can leave the master branch.

An important word here: The folder I'm working on has several project folders, each with its own .git repo. However, I changed files only in one of those project folders--all other folders had only unchanged files.

My question is this: What would be the reason why I would have a merge conflict with any file upon stashing then switching from the temp branch back to master given the condition of my files as itemized above in the bulleted list? I would think I could just stash, switch to master without fuss, then pop (unstash) when once again checking out the Temp branch...

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like VS botched the stash, I guess maybe that's obvious? Does VS show you what git did? A log, or a status of some kind? Have you used the CLI to look at anything?

Comment: Yeah Visual Studio has had a history of stash related issues... it sounds to me like after the switch it tried to apply the stash.

Comment: OK, I will use SmartGit to see what information was stashed and will try not to use VS again in the manner described (i.e., to stash). Stashing was added relatively recently, so it's entirely possible that it remains buggy (although I wouldn't have expected that because VS 2019 has been out for about 2 years now)... Meanwhile, I'll see if anyone else weighs in...